# nstimer stop when touch the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a timer class, with a nstimer inside, who push notification to a uitableviewcontroller, and the notification object(value of the timer) is affected in a uitableviewcell. My problem is when I touch the screen to scroll, the timer stop, NSTimer don't start in a other thread? How I can fix this problem.

My timerClass

```
#import "timerEtape.h"
#import "FonctionUtile.h"
#import "Mission.h"

static timerEtape *sngTimerEtape = nil;

@implementation timerEtape

@synthesize repeatingTimerEtape;
@synthesize dateComp;
@synthesize questionCircuit;
@synthesize b_Pause;

+(timerEtape *) singletonTimer
{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (sngTimerEtape == nil ) 
        {
            sngTimerEtape = [[timerEtape alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return sngTimerEtape;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        b_Pause = FALSE;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)startTimer {

    [repeatingTimerEtape invalidate];

    NSString * temps; 

    if (questionCircuit) {

        temps = [[Mission singletonMission].circuitTerrain valeurChampEtapeCircuitEnCours:@"et_temps_etape" :FALSE];
    }
    else {
        temps = [[Mission singletonMission].histoireTerrain valeurChampQuestion:@"hi_temps_etape" :FALSE];
    }

    if (!b_Pause) {
        [dateComp setHour:0];
        [dateComp setMinute:[[FonctionUtile gauche:temps :2] intValue]];
        [dateComp setSecond:[[FonctionUtile droite:temps :2] intValue]];
    }
    else {
        b_Pause = FALSE;
    }

    self.repeatingTimerEtape = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabelTimerEtape:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)pause
{
    self.b_Pause = TRUE;
    [repeatingTimerEtape invalidate];
}

-(void)updateLabelTimerEtape:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{

    if ([dateComp second] == 0) {

        if ([dateComp minute] == 0) {
            if ([dateComp hour] != 0) {
                [dateComp setHour:[dateComp hour] -1];
                [dateComp setMinute:59];
                [dateComp setSecond:59];
            }
            else {
                [repeatingTimerEtape invalidate];
                [delegate performSelector:touchAction];
            }

        }
        else {
            [dateComp setMinute:[dateComp minute] -1];
            [dateComp setSecond:59];
        }
    }
    else {
        [dateComp setSecond:[dateComp second] -1];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"rafraichirTimerEtape" object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", [dateComp minute],[dateComp second]]];
}

-(void)setTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action {
    delegate = target;
    touchAction = action;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [dateComp release];
    [repeatingTimerEtape release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and when I receive the notification in my uitableviewcontroller class

```
-(void)rafraichirTimerEtape:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [tempsRestant release];
    tempsRestant = [[notification object]copy];

    [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = [notification object];
}
```

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered with this problem before. In fact, NSTimer does not run in another thread, it always run in the thread which it is started. There is a runloop concept in iphone sdk, you should read it from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) to understand timers. In this concept, you push some jobs into runloop and runloop implements them sequentially. The main thread is always a run loop and ui jobs are run there. So if you start your timer in the main thread, it will be affected by ui processing. You should start a new thread, configure it as a run loop and start your timers there.

Edit: Here is a sample code from the link that I posted. threadMain is the first function which the thread starts.

```
- (void) threadMain
{
    NSRunLoop* myRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    // Create and schedule the timer.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
                selector:@selector(doFireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSInteger loopCount = 10;

    do
    {
        // Run the run loop 10 times to let the timer fire.
        [myRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
        loopCount--;
    }
    while (loopCount);
}
```

if you want runloop to run infinitely, but terminate it with a condition, use this instead

```
BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global

NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
      selector:@selector(doFireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
      beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```